# Can't use Stripe in iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, app-store, stripe-payments, appstore-approval

So I went through the trouble of implementing a Stripe payment system in my app, and submitted the app for review a few days ago. My app got rejected and Apple notified me that you *have* to use the In-App Purchase API for any payment system. This just doesn't seem right - why does Stripe even have an iOS SDK in that case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by Apple support.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use Stripe in an iOS app.
Apple accepts it when the customer can buy something which is not digital. for example your Instagram pictures printed on a mug, a computer and so on.

But if you use Stripe for something like a subscription (like a "gold access" to a revue) or to buy credits for a game, Apple will refuse the app and force you to use In-app purchase.

take a look here:

> There are a couple different ways to integrate payments into your iOS app: Apple Pay and In-App Purchases. It’s important to understand
> when each option should be used.
>
> You can use Apple Pay to sell physical goods such as groceries,
> clothing, and appliances. Also use Apple Pay for services such as club
> memberships, hotel reservations, and tickets for events. These
> transactions will be processed through Stripe and you’ll only need to
> pay Stripe’s processing fee. You can read more about Apple Pay here.
>
> You are required to use Apple’s In-App Purchase API to sell virtual goods such as premium content for your app, and subscriptions for digital content. Specifically, Apple’s developer terms require that the In-App Purchase API must be used for digital “content, functionality, or services” such as premium features or credits. If you use the In-App Purchase API, the transactions will be processed by Apple, which will charge a fee of 30% of the total transaction.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-and-stripe-tos-and-fees
hope it helps

Comment: Apple's requirements are utterly unacceptable. We have a platform with a back-end API and 3 client apps (web/android/ios). We're using Stripe for subscriptions, we sell 3 plans each with a different quota and features (e.g. how many records you can make per month, how much disk space you can use, etc.). The mobile apps themselves are free to use, nothing to be unlocked. Users need a confirmed account and a Stripe subscription to access all 3 apps. What do we do in this situation? We can’t have users having multiple subscriptions on Apple and Stripe.